# The server does not support SSL connections node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to establish a connection with my local postgres database and use express to do api endpoints. I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

```js
//db.js

const { Pool } = require("pg");
const pg = require("pg");

require("dotenv").config(); //get credentials

pg.defaults.ssl = true;

const connectionString = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
  ? process.env.DATABASE_URL
  : `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASS}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}`;

const conn = new Pool({ 
  connectionString: connectionString,
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});

module.exports = conn;
```

```
//index.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const pool = require("./db"); //stores super secret db info
const cors = require("cors");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); // => req.body
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/apiv1/:tier", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { date, tier } = req.params;
        const allData = await pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM previous WHERE tier=$1 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 25;", 
            [tier]
            );
        const results = allData.rows;
        console.log(results)
        // const output = { "data": Object.fromEntries(
        //     results.map(
        //         item => [item.pokemon, item]
        //         ))
        //     };
        // res.json(output);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    };
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

My credentials are valid, and my landing page loads, but when I try to go to `localhost:5500/apiv1/anything`, I get an error page and the message `The server does not support SSL connections` in my console, but I have taken the steps to allow for SSL connections.

Comment: What exactly are the steps you took to enable `https:` transactions? There's nothing about that in what you posted.

Comment: What's the full URL.  Is it -> `http://localhost:5500/apiv1/anything` by any chance, if so your not doing SSL.   Also what's actually saying the error?, `localhost` in the browser is known as a secure context, so for development reasons any API that requires a secure context will still work on `localhost`..

Comment: "but I have taken the steps to allow for SSL connections."  maybe you have done so, but you have provided zero description of what those steps were (on the server side).  Since the error specifies the server, that is what you need to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ssl is not enabled in your local postgreSQL server.

In `db.js` remove the ssl option and it should work:

```
const conn = new Pool({ 
  connectionString: connectionString,
  // ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false } // remove this line
});
```